# How to change CSS of columns - ReactTable

Tags: css, reactjs, resize, react-table

I am using [react-table](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-table#installation) in my application.

I am stuck in doing one thing i.e. changing the `CSS` of `columns` while a column is being resized.

Currently when you `resize` a column only `cursor` changes. What I want is to add `border` to the `selected column`.

I searched for this on `SO` and `google` as well. But couldn't find anything useful. And In the documentation as well nothing is mentioned about this topic as well.

**Update**

Now I am able to add border while dragging the column while resizing. I am able to do so by adding and removing the class.

What I did to do so:

Created a var in the state for className:

```
  this.state = {
         addBorder: null
   }
```

Passed this class name in my column:

```
     const columns = [{
    Header: 'Name',
    accessor: 'name', // String-based value accessors!,
    headerClassName: this.state.addBorder,
    className: this.state.addBorder
}, {
    Header: 'Age',
    accessor: 'age',
    Cell: props => <span className='number'>{2}</span> // Custom cell components!
}, {
    id: 'friendName', // Required because our accessor is not a string
    Header: 'Friend Name',
    accessor: d => d.friend.name // Custom value accessors!
}, {
    Header: props => <span>Friend Age</span>, // Custom header components!
    accessor: 'friend.age'
}];

return (
    <div onMouseUp={this.handleMouseUp}>
    <ReactTable
        data={data}
        columns={columns} 
        resizable={true}
        onResizedChange={(col, e) => {
            const column = col[col.length-1];
            this.setState({addBorder: column.id})
        }} />
        </div>
)
}
```

To remove the class when dragging ends:

```
   handleMouseUp (e) {
    this.setState({addBorder: null});
}
```

> **But I am still not able to add border on hover.**

Now, I am sending my custom HTML in header props. And in my  HTML I have made an extra div. And I have moved this div to right. And on hover of this div, I am emitting mouse events and changing CSS accordingly.

But Existing div in the header that is responsible for resizing column is overlapping with my Div.

```
  Header: props => <div className='header-div'> Name <div onMouseOver = {() => {
        console.log('mose');
        this.setState({className: 'addBorder'});
    }} className='hover-div' onMouseOut = {() => {console.log('sdasd');this.setState({className: null});}}> </div></div> ,
```

Comment: I don't think there is a handler to do this. However you could make up a hack with `onResizedChange` callback.

Answer (score 6):

> From what I understand, you want to add some border when you hover over a column header. If my understanding is correct, you can use `:hover` pseudo selector over the header class

```
.hdrCls:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

**Update :**

You can manipulate state in `onResizedChange` handler exposed by react-table

```
onResizedChange={(newResized, event) => {
  let resizedCol = newResized.slice(-1)[0].id;
  if(this.state.activeCol !== resizedCol) {
    this.setState({
      activeCol: resizedCol,
      resizing: true
    })
  }
}}
```

Also, make sure you have to make the `resizing` state to `false` on `mouseup` event. For that I have come up with the below solution.

```
componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
  if (this.state.resizing && !state.resizing) {
    document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
  } else if (!this.state.resizing && state.resizing) {
    document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
  }
}

onMouseUp = (evt) => {
  this.setState({
    activeCol: '',
    resizing: false
  });
  evt.stopPropagation();
  evt.preventDefault();
}
```

For reference:

```js
const ReactTable = window.ReactTable.default

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      activeCol: '',
      resizing: false
    }
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate(props, state) {
    if (this.state.resizing && !state.resizing) {
      document.addEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
    } else if (!this.state.resizing && state.resizing) {
      document.removeEventListener('mouseup', this.onMouseUp);
    }
  }
  
  onMouseUp = (evt) => {
    this.setState({
      activeCol: '',
      resizing: false
    });
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();
  }
  
  render() {
    const data = [{
      name:"Mark",
      age:24
    },
    {
      name:"Derek",
      age:26
    }]

    const columns = [{
          Header: 'Name',
          accessor: 'name', // String-based value accessors!,
          headerClassName: 'hdrCls',
          className: (this.state.activeCol === 'name') && this.state.resizing ? 'borderCellCls' : 'defaultCellCls'
      }, {
          Header: 'Age',
          accessor: 'age',
          headerClassName: 'hdrCls',
          className: (this.state.activeCol === 'age') && this.state.resizing ? 'borderCellCls' : 'defaultCellCls'
      }];

    return <ReactTable
      data = { data }
      columns = { columns }
      showPagination= {false}
      onResizedChange={(newResized, event) => {
        let resizedCol = newResized.slice(-1)[0].id;
        if(this.state.activeCol !== resizedCol) {
          this.setState({
            activeCol: resizedCol,
            resizing: true
          })
        }
      }}
    />
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById("app"))
```

```css
.hdrCls:hover {
  border: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
}


.borderCellCls {
  border-right: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
}

.defaultCellCls {
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.6/react-table.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-table/6.7.6/react-table.css"></link>
<div id="app"></div>
```

You can play around with CSS. Hope this is what you want and hope this helps.

**Update:**

I think you have to play with CSS to achieve what you desire.

```
.borderCellCls {
   border-right: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
   border-left: 2px solid rgba(0,0,0,0.6) !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @dev, In your solution only one column is highlighting when I hover the edge of the column. What I want is to add border in while column rather than adding on one cell.

Comment: @Dalvik, yes according to the above logic, when you try to resize a particular column, that column would get border. This was my understanding. Correct me if I am wrong, what you want is the same behavior but instead of cells getting highlighted whole column should show border during resizing. Right ??

Comment: @Dalvik, I think if the above answer is close to what you want, and the only problem being, the border should be shown to the column instead of cell, I would suggest you can manipulate this with CSS to achieve the desired result. But happy to help. I will try again once I get time.

Answer (score 4):

If you are here to find out **how to set className to a column cell (with the react-table)**, here is the **solution**:

**1)**

```
<tr
            
              {...row.getRowProps()}
            >
              {row.cells.map((cell) => (
                <td
                  {...cell.getCellProps([
                    {
                      className: cell.column.className, // pay attention to this
                      style: cell.column.style,
                      // set here your other custom props
                    },
                  ])}
                >
                  {cell.render('Cell')}
                </td>
              ))}
            </tr>
```

**2)**

```
  const columns = React.useMemo(
() => [
  {
    Header: 'Date',
    accessor: 'date',
    minWidth: 70,
    className: 'text-dark fw-bolder fs-6 min-w-70px', // pass className props here
    headerClassName: 'text-muted', // or another props like this one
  }]
  
<Table columns={columns} ... />
```

And finally, those **props will be passed to your cells**

Comment: 'className' maps to the attribute that React uses to specify CSS class on DOM elements - https://reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html

Answer (score 1):

For TypeScript support follow the instructions in [DefinitelyTyped](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table), ie. create the file `/src/types/react-table-config.d.ts` with the content from the instructions, then add the following to it to support custom properties on your column (add more properties in the last line as required):

```
  // Added to support classes to template from:
  // https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/tree/master/types/react-table
  export interface ColumnInstance<
    D extends Record<string, unknown> = Record<string, unknown>
  > extends Omit<ColumnInterface<D>, 'id'>,
      ColumnInterfaceBasedOnValue<D>,
      UseTableColumnProps<D>,
      Record<headerClassName | className, string> {}
```