# React Table TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isGrouped')

Tags: react-table

I am using
`react-table@7.7.0` and
`@types/react-table@7.7.9`
Together with `react-table-config.d.ts`
from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64673951/13172890).

In my project, I have a table that uses the `useExpanded` plugin and works perfectly. But when I add `useRowSelect` and `toggleRowSelected` is called it crashes. *I tried to create a simple example of that error with js but I couldn't.*

### Things I tried:

- Setting `selectedRowIds` manually using the `initialState` of the
  table **works**.
- Adding the `useGroupBy` plugin **doesn't help.** I thought it might help since the error is related to `isGrouped`.
- Using `toggleRowSelected(rowId)` instead of `row.toggleRowSelected()` **doesn't help.**

The error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'isGrouped')
    at handleRowById (useRowSelect.js:157:1)
    at useRowSelect.js:166:1
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at handleRowById (useRowSelect.js:166:1)
    at reducer$8 (useRowSelect.js:170:1)
    at useTable.js:124:1
    at Array.reduce (<anonymous>)
    at useTable.js:117:1
    at updateReducer (react-dom.development.js:15318:1)
    at Object.useReducer (react-dom.development.js:16425:1)
    at Object.useReducer (react.development.js:1512:1)
    at useTable (useTable.js:57:1)
    at LeftTable (index.tsx:137:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:14985:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:17356:1)
    at beginWork (react-dom.development.js:19063:1)
    at HTMLUnknownElement.callCallback (react-dom.development.js:3945:1)
    at Object.invokeGuardedCallbackDev (react-dom.development.js:3994:1)
    at invokeGuardedCallback (react-dom.development.js:4056:1)
    at beginWork$1 (react-dom.development.js:23964:1)
    at performUnitOfWork (react-dom.development.js:22776:1)
    at workLoopSync (react-dom.development.js:22707:1)
    at renderRootSync (react-dom.development.js:22670:1)
    at performSyncWorkOnRoot (react-dom.development.js:22293:1)
    at react-dom.development.js:11327:1
    at unstable_runWithPriority (scheduler.development.js:468:1)
    at runWithPriority$1 (react-dom.development.js:11276:1)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueueImpl (react-dom.development.js:11322:1)
    at flushSyncCallbackQueue (react-dom.development.js:11309:1)
    at discreteUpdates$1 (react-dom.development.js:22420:1)
    at discreteUpdates (react-dom.development.js:3756:1)
    at dispatchDiscreteEvent (react-dom.development.js:5889:1)
```

[Here is the codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-star-0x1v2?file=/src/App.js) (doesn't recreate the problem)